# Keep MySQL strict mode disabled after server restart (Hostinger VPS with Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: mysql, vps, ubuntu

So I have a site hosted on VPS Hosting Plan 2 of Hostinger, and it uses MySQL for the database, with the OS of my Virtual Machine being Ubuntu 18.04.

I have to keep MySQL's `strict mode` disabled globally the entire time for some parts of the site to work. For context, I am only managing the server end at the moment, so I cannot fix the parts of this site that require me to disable `strict mode`. Those fixes are on the developers' end, and they'll eventually handle them at some point.

Now, the problem I am facing is that when I disable `strict mode`, it automatically gets enabled after several hours (or a day). This is due to the scheduled server restarts that Hostinger's VPS servers seem to have. Whenever the server restarts, MySQL's `strict mode` gets re-enabled.

How can I do it so that `strict mode` is permanently disabled until I turn it back on myself? I obviously don't want to be turning it on every few hours... :)

Edit: I currently used `set global sql_mode='';` to disable MySQL `strict mode`.

Comment: how do you disable the mode? is there a administration panel involved?

Comment: @djdomi I use the terminal as everyone does. I go into the mysql command line and run a command `set global sql_mode='';`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you disable mysql strict mode using below command, it will get revert after the server restart.

> set global sql_mode='';

To set/disable it permanently, you have to edit the value in mysql conf file.

**/etc/mysql/my.cnf**  or **/etc/my.cnf** based on your OS.

Find the following line:

```
sql_mode = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Replace it with the line below:
If the line is not found, insert the line under the [mysqld] section (if there is no [mysqld] section, pls create it).

```
[mysqld] 
sql_mode= ""
```

Restart the MySQL service for the change to take effect.

Comment: Hi, I'll try this today. But If I am not wrong, doesn't running `set global sql_mode='';` under the hood simply change the my.cnf file?

Comment: Btw, I have mentioned my OS in the question, it is Ubuntu 18.04. Just letting you know since you said "based on your OS".

Comment: You answer works! thanks a lot.